# If statments are always executed

Tags: c++, if-statement, assignment-operator, comparison-operators

Help

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
const float pi = 3.14;
void Odabir(int);
int main(){
    int choose;
    cout << "Odaberite 1 2 ili 3" << endl;
    cin >> choose;
    Odabir(choose);
    return 0;
}
void Odabir(int choose){
    if (choose = 1){
        float b, vb;
        cout << "Unesite duljinu stranice b: " << endl;
        cin >> b;
        cout << "Unesite duljinu visine na stranicu b vb: " << endl;
        cin >> vb;
        cout << "Povrsina raznostranicnog trokuta je: " << ((b*vb) / 2) << endl;
    }
    if (choose = 2){
        float r;
        cout << "Unesite duljinu polumjera: " << endl;
        cin >> r;
        cout << "Povrsina kruga je: " << pow(r, 2)*pi << endl;
    }

}
```

I have been trying to solve that for few hours and I can't get thru it, it looks like when I set choose value all three if clauses get executed and printed.

Comment: You may want to use `switch` instead of `if`s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the assignment operator `( = )` instead of the comparison operator `( == )` in the if statements in the function.

For example

```
if (choose = 1){
          ^^^
```

Write instead

```
if (choose == 1){
          ^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning the variable choose instead of comparing it inside the Odabir function.

for instance, choose **=** 1 should be choose **==** 1